# mod_php APC confused by symlinks, includes same files twice - why?

Tags: php, caching, symlink, apc

I have an Apache vhost set up for the folder (say `website`) which is a symlink to another one linking to a folder with a current release (say `website_N`) where N is release number (`website -> website_123`). When a new release is deployed, another folder named `website_N+1` is created and when its content is ready `website` symlink is recreated to link to that new folder (`website -> website124`).

This setup seems to confuse APC's cache of includes. Sometimes (not always, which is annoying) after a new deployment and the following symlink switch `include` and `require` instructions in application start to result in redeclaration errors:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Foobar in /absolute/path/to/deployment/physical/folder/website_N/include_foobar.php

`website_N` folder in that message is usually one of the old build folders, sometimes even no longer existing. But sometimes error is generated showing the right physical location of the most recent release folder. What stays the same is "cannot redeclare" error for classes loaded for the first time.

I'm pretty confident that is an APC issue because every time that happens adding `apc_clear_cache()` to application bootstrap resolves the problem.

I guess that happens because different releases reside under the same symlink folder sharing the same "unresolved" path. As a result it could be that old include connections are loaded for precompiled images, and another attempt to include a dependency is performed for its "resolved" path, so it appears as a new one and results in double include and following redeclaration error. Although this theory might not make much sense, I don't understand APC internals very well.

There are many ways around that (to clear cache as a part of deployment process being the obvious one), but if anyone can explain to me the mechanism behind that error, i.e. what in this setup breaks APC behaviour and at which point (and why physically removed folder paths sometimes appear in those error messages) that'd be great.

Comment: I've not gone digging in the code yet (but I fear I might have to, soon). I'm using Capifony/Capistrano, which does the symlink flip too.  The APC web interface (apc.php script) shows the absolute paths of the cached scripts, so it does know they are different. Clearing the cache is an interesting one, I seem to have to do it twice (first time right after the symlink switch seems not to work)

Comment: I'm no longer working on that project, but I think I remember that clearing the cache doesn't *always* help which might actually mean it is not relevant at all :(

Answer (score 1):

I use TYPO3 and had the same problem. TYPO3 caches quite a lot. When changing the symlink to another source it is neccesary to go into the TYPO3 installation folder using a shell and manually delete the cached files.

After that all is good. It took a day to figure out.